# Add a date to a list of dataframes by extracting it from the filename

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of multiple dataframes `dfs`.

The dataframes come from files that have dates in its name. Eg. *FilenameYYYYMMDD.xlsx*

```
files = [str(file) for file in Path(/dir)]
dfs = [pd.read_excel(file, header=1)] for file in files]
```

I can extract the date from the file names:

```
date_extract = re.search('[0-9]{8}',files[0...20])
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_extract[0...20], '%Y%m%d').date()
```

But how can I assign to each `df` its respective date (by adding a column called 'Date')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your using `pathlib` we can use a dictionary to hold your dataframes and use a quick regex to extract the date, when we concat the dataframes the index will be set to the date.

```
import re
from pathlib import Path
dfs = {
    re.search('(\d{4}.*).xlsx',f.name).group(1): pd.read_excel(f,header=1)
    for f in Path(
        /dir
    ).glob("*.xlsx")
}
```

---

```
print(pd.concat(dfs))

  Unnamed: 0    e    f    c    d
20200610 0            0  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         1            1  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         2            2  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         3            3  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         4            4  1.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         5            5  0.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
         6            6  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         7            7  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         8            8  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         9            9  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         10          10  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         11          11  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         12          12  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         13          13  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         14          14  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         15          15  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         16          16  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         17          17  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         18          18  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         19          19  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         20          20  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         21          21  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         22          22  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         23          23  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         24          24  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
         25          25  0.0  0.0  NaN  NaN
20201012 0            0  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0
         1            1  NaN  NaN  0.0  0.0
         2            2  NaN  NaN  1.0  0.0
         3            3  NaN  NaN  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: What I need is to add an entire column `df[date]` filled with the respective dates.

Comment: @eduardo2111 just add `reset_index()` to the end? you can rename the column then. like `pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(0).rename(columns={'level_0' : 'Date'})`

Comment: It works! Thank you one more time @Datanovice ( you've been helping me recurrently these days).